# Grouped function between 2 columns in a pandas.DataFrame?

Tags: pandas, grouping, correlation

I have a dataframe that has multiple numerical data columns, and a 'group' column. I want to get the output of various functions over two of the columns, for each group.

Example data and function:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({"Dummy":[1,2]*6, "X":[1,3,7]*4, 
                       "Y":[2,3,4]*4, "group":["A","B"]*6})

def RMSE(X):
  return(np.sqrt(np.sum((X.iloc[:,0] - X.iloc[:,1])**2)))
```

I want to do something like

```
group_correlations = df[["X", "Y"]].groupby('group').apply(RMSE)
```

But if I do that, the 'group' column isn't in the dataframe. If I do it the other way around, like this:

```
group_correlations = df.groupby('group')[["X", "Y"]].apply(RMSE)
```

Then the column selection doesn't work:

```
df.groupby('group')[['X', 'Y']].head(1)

         Dummy  X  Y group
group                     
A     0      1  1  2     A
B     1      2  3  3     B
```

the Dummy column is still included, so the function will calculate RMSE on the wrong data.

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do? I know I could do a for loop over the different groups, and subselect the columns manually, but I'd prefer to do it the pandas way, if there is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug (or that grabbing multiple columns in a groupby is not implemented?), a workaround is to pass in the groupby column directly:

```
In [11]: df[['X', 'Y']].groupby(df['group']).apply(RMSE)
Out[11]:
group
A        4.472136
B        4.472136
dtype: float64
```

To see it's the same:

```
In [12]: df.groupby('group')[['X', 'Y']].apply(RMSE)  # wrong
Out[12]:
group
A        8.944272
B        7.348469
dtype: float64

In [13]: df.iloc[:, 1:].groupby('group')[['X', 'Y']].apply(RMSE)  # correct: ignore dummy col
Out[13]:
group
A        4.472136
B        4.472136
dtype: float64
```

#### More robust implementation:

To avoid this completely, you could change RMSE to select the columns by name:

```
In [21]: def RMSE2(X, left_col, right_col):
             return(np.sqrt(np.sum((X[left_col] - X[right_col])**2)))

In [22]: df.groupby('group').apply(RMSE2, 'X', 'Y')  # equivalent to passing lambda x: RMSE2(x, 'X', 'Y'))
Out[22]:
group
A        4.472136
B        4.472136
dtype: float64
```

*Thanks to @naught101 for pointing out the sweet apply syntax to avoid the lambda.*

Comment: Thanks, the first solution is good, but the latter two are not really portable (to different sets of columns). Since this is probably a bug (https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6524), I think your first solution is probably the best workaround for now.

Comment: @naught101 passing the column names into RMSE2 could also work / make more portable

Comment: is that RMSE function working for you with `.apply(RMSE)` (even without the grouping)? I swear it was working for me a minute ago, but now it seems not to be...

Comment: @naught101 You have to use axis=1, that is `df.apply(RMSE2, 1)`.

Comment: That wasn't working either, but using `df.groupby().aggregate(RMSE)` does work. Re: passing column names: excellent idea, I wasn't aware that was possible. Thanks!

Comment: @naught101 added that as soln!

Comment: Thanks, Andy. Apply actually passes the values correctly, so you don't need the lambda. I edited the answer to use the simpler syntax, and avoid the lambda.

Comment: @naught101 the eidt got rejected (code edits usually do) so put it in myself, good spot, that is definitely neater! :)